# Recommend please MySQL Profiler (preferably free)

Tags: mysql, profiler

I tried "Jet Profiler for MySQL", but I did not like

Comment: Tell us more.  What didn't you like?  What didn't it do that you do want it to do?  Details details details!

Comment: do not like because:
- You can not see all the queries
- There is no possibility of co-mapping diagrams (threads, tables, schemas)
- An uncomfortable management of chart

Answer (score 4):

Single graphical profiler for mysql is Jet Profiler. [see review](http://mysql-tools.com/en/overview-mysql-tools/73-other/91-review-jet-profiler-for-mysql.html)

Answer (score 4):

[SHOW PROFILES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html) or [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) are directly available in MySQL and provide tons of information.

I'm guess some MySQL gui will be able to present it graphically...

Edit: phpMyAdmin has support for this as well, you just need to enable profiling under displayed executed query, you can try that on [demo server](http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/trunk-config/sql.php?db=kaaskop&table=Sheet1&profiling=on).

Answer (score 1):

What about using [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) right inside mysql?

Comment: I am interested in all types of queries. and it would be a graphical representation of the data collected.

Answer (score -1):

Find and open your MySQL configuration file, usually /etc/mysql/my.cnf on Ubuntu. Look for the section that says “Logging and Replication”

```
# * Logging and Replication
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.

log = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

or in newer versions of mysql, comment OUT this lines of codes

```
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
log_error                = /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

Just uncomment the “log” variable to turn on logging. Restart MySQL with this command:
    sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart

Now we’re ready to start monitoring the queries as they come in. Open up a new terminal and run this command to scroll the log file, adjusting the path if necessary.

```
tail -f /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```